# A quicker method than binomial expansion to expand $(2-3i)^{10}$

Tags: complex-numbers

The other day I was speaking to my teacher about complex numbers and I was expanding something like $(2-3i)^{10}$ using binomial expansion. He said that it was probably the quickest method, but then corrected himself, hinting at a quicker way to expand it.

Anyone have any ideas what this quicker method was?

Comment: Convert to polar form?  Also $ (2-3i)^{10}=((2-3i)^2)^5$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The angle isn't nice as far as I can tell, so you'd have to do some tricky trigonometry to get the exact value from the polar form. But for an approximation it's probably a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I just made the numbers up at random. The actual question that my teacher was referring to at the time was different, so might have had a nicer angle. It is possible he was referring to polar form as that is something that we will cover.

Comment: May be your teacher had [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in mind. Probably a bit faster, but I don't think it gives significant savings in your case. It really shines when you do, for example, modular exponentiation with an outrageously high exponent.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  Cf. my comment to Dr. Graubner’s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2-3i)^2=-5-12i$$ and $$(-5-12i)^5=-3125-37500i+180000+432000i-518400-248832i=-341525+145668i$$
———————————————

Addendum to answer question in comment:

Sometimes it’s easier to take powers of complex numbers by converting to polar form.  For example $(1+i)^{10}=(\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4})^{10}=32e^{i\pi/2}=32i$

Comment: Thanks, I see this could be what my teacher was referring to. If possible, could you demonstrate how you would go about it by converting to polar form? To make it easier you don’t have to use my example, many thanks.

Comment: In this case the argument of the base is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, and I fail to see how you get the phase factor fast in such a case.